# What do I do if a question belongs here but is answered on Super User SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question [How to destroy a CD/DVD rom safely?](https://superuser.com/questions/660221/) already has good answers on the sister site Super User Stack Exchange, but I think it belongs on this site.  If the question didn't exist there already, I'd ask it here.

What should I do in this case? Should I ask the SuperUser admins to migrate the question?  Should I ask the question here and answer it with a link and a short summary of the answer given there?  Is there instead some other administrative action you can take?  Thank you in advance for the help.

By the way, could we just check [the list of their questions with the [security] tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security) and steal all [the good ones](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security?sort=votes), or at least all the ones that are also approperiate here?

Update: I have not have made this my goal clear in the question.  If someone searches "destroy cd" in the search box of Information Security SE, he doesn't currently find a relevant question.  I'd like the answer for that question searchable, because it's a good question that can occur to others too.  Please answer this meta question in a way that tells how to make it possible to make that and similar questions searchable.

Answer (score 5):

The question got some good answers and interest over there, and while we do have an excellent dupe and an associated blog post, it is not necessary to migrate it here.

If it had no answers there I would suggest migration, but questions can be on-topic on various sites.

If you do feel strongly about it, you could flag it for a mod over there to migrate, and they can decide. We would have to close it as a dupe here anyway.

For questions over 30 days old, migration is not an option anyway, so looking at the longer list of security-tagged questions I think you would be wasting your time.

Feel free to flag new security questions there for migration **if** they are off-topic there or they aren't getting good answers. But remember, we don't need to steal questions or answers.

Comment: What dupe are you talking about?  I might not have made this my goal clear in the question.  If someone searches "destroy cd" in the search box of Information Security SE, he doesn't currently find a relevant question.  I'd like the answer searchable here.

Comment: This question is pretty much a dupe, despite it being for hard drives rather than CD's: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11313/485

Comment: No, it is not a dupe.  A hard disk is inside a hard case and stores data magnetically, which differs a lot from a cd.  The best way to destroy them is also very different, as you can see from the answers: you destroy a cd with a shredder, which won't work for a hard disk.

Comment: Ok, maybe you destroy a hard disk with a shredder too, but it's a very different shredder.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the point of both those answers, and the ones on the CD question. Neither has a single conclusion - they both offer loads of options but agree that mechanical destruction or fire are the way to go. There is no good reason to bring that question over here.